# Title Jupyter cells like in Colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

Colab allows titling cells via `# @title NAME`, enabling eased navigation across multiple collapsed cells:

[image]

Anything of sort doable in Jupyter - in particular, JupyterLab?

Comment: I like the [jupyterlab-toc](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-toc) extension because  you get the easy navigation without you even needing to add cell titles.

Answer (score -1):

you can change the cell to be markdown with the keyboard shortcut
`esc+m`
[image]